# Cleaning Function not Working in UseEffect Hook During Component Unmount in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In react native app, there are two components `A` and `B` in `App.js` which toggle with `k` state change.

`App.js`

```
...

const App = () => {
      const [ k, setK ] = useState(false);

      const toggleK = () => setK(!k);

      if(k) {
            return <A />;
      }else {
            return <B toggleK={toggleK} />;
      }
};
...
```

In `A`, `setInterval` is initialized in `useffect`. It calls async function every 10 seconds. But when it unmounts on `K` state change in `App.js`, the cleaning function is not run (no `A unmounting...` is logged) and so does the `clearInterval`.

Any thing I'm doing wrong here?

```
...

const A = () => {
      const [ someState, setSomeState ] = useState(...);

      let timer;

      useEffect(() => {
            if(!timer) {
                  timer = setInterval(async () => await run_async_func(), 10000);
            }

            return () => {
                  console.log('A unmounting...');
                  clearInterval(timer);
            };
      }, [ someState ]);
};
...
```

Comment: What's inside `useState(...)` in `A`? You're passing `someState` in dependency array, which means that **A unomounting...** will not run unless someState changes.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar Oh shoot. Yeah, overlooked that! Now it works.

Comment: @Waleed93 If first part of useEffect is calling why not second (I mean if setInterval part is calling why not clearInterval) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with useRef().

```
const A = () => {
 const timer = useRef()
  const [ someState, setSomeState ] = useState(...);


  useEffect(() => {
        if(!timer) {
              timer.current = setInterval(async () => await run_async_func(), 10000);
        }

        return () => {
              console.log('A unmounting...');
              clearInterval(timer.current);
        };
  }, [ someState ]);
};
```

Comment: Using `useRef` is not different from what I did. It's not just about `clearInterval`, the above line also doesn't run. Basically, the cleaning operation during unmounting of component `A` isn't working despite `k` state changing to `false` and rendering component `B`

Comment: Can you please create a codesandbox link then. Also I think it should work I am doing exactly same in many of my projects and it is working. Also you are declaring a variable inside a component so on every render that variable is being declared again that's why useref is used so I would really recommend that you try it once if it doesn't work then please create a codesandbox for me to play around

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved the issue**

- What was causing the issue?

A. Overlooked the `someState` in `useEffect` dependency array. Basically, cleaner function will only run if any variable in dependency array mutates. So, I used another `useEffect` without any dependencies (see below). Thanks @TayyabMazhar for pointing out this

```
...
const A = () => {
      const [ someState, setSomeState ] = useState(...);

      let timer;

      useEffect(() => {
            if(!timer) {
                  timer = setInterval(async () => await run_async_func(), 10000);
            }
      }, [ someState ]);

      useEffect(() => {
            return () => {
                 console.log('A unmounting...');
                 clearInterval(timer);
            };
      }, []);
};
...
```